# Accessing JSON File Outside PHP root directory

Tags: c#, php, json

I have an application that is creating a JSON file and a PHP page that uses that JSON file to update the database. Now, I want the application and PHP page to be run on two different machines. SO, I ran the application on machine 1 and the JSON file created from application is stored in a 'Public' directory which outside the root of the PHP file. 
How do I ensure that PHP is able to access this file or rather where can I and how can I store that JSON file so that the PHP can use that?

JSON Structure from C#:

```
public class User_Group
{
    public int ID_UserGroup { get; set; }
    public string Name_UserGroup { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
public class User_Role
{
    public int ID_User { get; set; }
    public string Role_User { get; set; }
    public string User_Role_Description { get; set; }
    public List<User_Group> UserGroup { get; set; }
}

public class Stand_Orte
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public List<Modul> modul { get; set; }
}

public class Modul
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Seriennummer { get; set; }
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public string StandortID { get; set; }
    public List<Mess_Kanal> MessKanal { get; set; }
}

public class Mess_Kanal
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ModulID { get; set; }
    public List<LogMess_Daten> LogMessDaten { get; set; }
}

public class LogMess_Daten
{
    public string KanalID { get; set; }
    public string Zeitstempel { get; set; }

}


public class RootObject
{
    public int ID_Project { get; set; }
    public string Name_Project { get; set; }
    public int Receiver_ID { get; set; }
    public string Receiver_Name { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User_Role UserRole { get; set; }
    public Stand_Orte Standorte { get; set; }
}
```

PHP Decode:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("JSON_superproject.json");
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
```

if "JSON_superproject.json" is saved into for example K:\Public\ABC and i try to use it like: `file_get_contents@("K:\Public\ABC\JSON_superproject.json");` it doesn't work. 
It gives an error, that the file at K:\Public\ABC\JSON_superproject.json is not in the root directory.

How do I fix that?
Any ideas?

Thank you,
Revathy

Comment: Try to put same directoty where you site is hosted.

Comment: but that directory is not accessible from the second machine where the application is running.

Comment: file_get_contents is executed on server side not client side. If you have stored that file some where else then it is not possible to access.

Comment: I See. But is there any other way to access a file outside PHP root, in PHP? different function, other than file_get_contents?

Comment: I am not sure you want but if you want to read json file data to php application. Most of the time first upload file to that server and then process that file

Comment: I don't think this is much of a PHP problem. You want to access a file on another machine. I suppose you want to do that using internet? Then you need to somehow make that file available to the internet. Depending on which webserver you have, you need to put it in a public folder? For Apache, that would be somewhere in httpdocs for example. Does that help? If not, please specify how the two machines communicate.

Comment: yes, I want to read the JSON file created outside PHP root in my PHP code... :(

Comment: @Anorionil: Yes, You are right. Machine 1 creates a JSON file and stores it in a Public Folder (which is accessible by everyone), Machine 2 should access that file in a PHP page. But the PHP page is unable to get to that public folder. I am guessing the way I'm trying to access the file is wrong. `code`file_get_contents@("K:\Public\ABC\JSON_superproject.json");

Comment: If the file is public, you should be able to access it using a link like http: //www.yourdomain.com/ABC/JSON_superproject.json. If you have that working, you can get the file using file_get_contents("http: //www.yourdomain.com/ABC/JSON_superproject.json")

Comment: I have XAMPP running on both the machines. Now where should I put the JSON file created by machine 1 such that PHP can access it. The application on machine 1 also runs the PHP script, but internally it accesses the localhost of machine 2 (where the PHP file is stored). But, the problem arises when machine 1 runs the PHP file, but the PHP file in machine 2 expects the JSON file to be in its Root.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have at least the following options:

1. Create a directory inside the tree which is accessible to the PHP script and share it with the first machine and update the first app to put the file there.
2. Create a Task Scheduler job which regularly copies the file from Public to a place inside the tree which is accessible to the PHP script.
3. Push the file to the second machine using a HTTP POST to a PHP script which either just saves the file for further processing or directly process it.
4. Make the file accessible over web (i.e. start a new web server instance whose root directory is the directory with the file) and access the file over http/https. It does not matter whether the file would be served from the first or from the second server.
5. Opt-out from the security feature of PHP which denies access to files outside the PHP root (see http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). Basically, this option is not a good choice.

Comment: great, thank you for the different options. I will try these out..!! °--°

Comment: I have just added a new option (3).

Comment: that's awesome. thanks a lotfor your ideas. I am trying to use REST now to push the JSON data directly into MYSQL. !! all of these stuff are just overwhelming though.! --__--